# How do I unit test for failing tests?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, tdd, nose

I am trying to get started with nosetests and TDD on my own. From what I understand the point of unit testing is to test as much functionality of a function as possible. So what I want to do is add invalid parameters to my function and verify that this can not be done. For example, I am writing a simple add function

```
def addBowling(x, y):
    try:
        return x + y
    except TypeError:
        print('Exception occured: invalid types')
```

So for this function I want inputs like 'a' to raise an exception. In my nosetests I want to input 'a' like so.

```
def testAddNumbers():
    assert addBowling(3, 4) == 7
    assert addBowling(5, 0) == 5
    assert addBowling('a', 0) == TypeError
```

I want to have a couple asserts that will pass and one assert that will fail. When I run this test it tells me that 1 test failed. I am not sure if I am correct in my understanding but I want this test to say it passed because this is correct functionality for my function.

Any guidance on how to get the results that I am looking for?

Comment: That is the not the right of way to test the exception, you have to assert_raises and test it.

Comment: @Shivaraj thank you! that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a helpful commenter I was able to learn that assert raises is what I was looking for. I refactored my function so now all it does is add and used assert raises in my test, like so.

```
def addBowling(x, y):
        return x + y

def testAddNumbers():
    assert addBowling(3, 4) == 7
    assert addBowling(5, 0) == 5
    assert_raises(TypeError, addBowling, 'a', 2)
```

Don't forget to import from nose.tools assert_raises!